# Put SSJS directly on the server instead of the database

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Has somebody found a way to put a SSJS library directly on the server?

I tried to link with something like:

```
    <xp:script clientSide="false"
        src="http://something/mylib.jss">
    </xp:script>
```

It works fine with CSJS and css but a SSJS library brings me an error allthough the path is correct.

Anybody found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You create an OSGi plug-in than contains your SsJS. Check Nathan Freeman's [XSP toolkit on OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20SDK%20for%20Eclipse%20RCP) has a sample.

You are then deep in Java land and might decide to just stay there

Comment: Plus, you can't just put it on as SSJS. You need to write Java methods, creating references for each SSJS method mapping to the relevant Java method, also mapping parameters from SSJS "data types" to Java data types. And each needs registering with its own reference.

Comment: So actually its not just straight forward like css and js. Then design inheritance has to do do the task. Thanks for help

Comment: Nathan had an example that really works like a SsJS. No additions for mapping etc needed

Comment: Do you have the link somewhere because i cant find it. I have created my first plugin now but again the same issue with the missing SSJS. Thats the only thing thats left to finish my project

Comment: Google is hard, here is the link: http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20SDK%20for%20Eclipse%20RCP Feel free to accept the answer

Comment: XPages SDK for Eclipse RCP!=XSP toolkit. Not easy to find things if  the search string doesnt match. Thanks i will have a look at that.